# Can changelings be knocked out?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Not with a hypospray, but with a strong blow to the head, or a sufficiently powerful phaser blast. Could Odo, Laas, or the Female Changeling, etc., be knocked unconscious?

Comment: What is the purpose of questions like this? Fan Fiction? They are essentially `“What if ______ happened?”` questions from the [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Although the question does not sound open ended, unless there is canon about it, it is open-ended. Logic only works so well here. Odo doesn't actually have a head.

Comment: @calccrypto - In this case, it's not a what if? question. There's a canon description of him being knocked out.

Comment: @calccrypto Because I'm curious. What's the purpose of the questions you ask? Did you complain about the person who asked if a Borg could assimilate a Q?

Comment: @T-1000 no, because [someone already did](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67082/what-would-be-the-effect-of-a-borg-assimilating-a-q#comment136647_67082), and I didnt find that question too bad. At least there was a memorable canon scene about it. This question however, feels like it was just randomly thought up. These questions irk me because they ask pretty specific things that can easily flood this site.

Comment: @T-1000 To me, questions like this invite other questions like: "did Sisko ever break his left index finger", followed by "did Sisko ever break his right index finger", followed by "did Kira ever break her left index finger", etc. They are randomly thought up and not relevant to anything (except to maybe one episode). And I don't want this site to be flooded with such questions.

Comment: Asking about the physiology of a certain species is hardly "random." It's also quite relevant. Likening such questions to the examples you gave is ridiculous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Odo gets knocked out a couple of time, firstly (As @KyleJones has pointed out) in [DS9: Vortex](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/412.txt) by what appears to be a blow to the shoulder. At this point he's in changeling form.

> But as they pass through the tunnel, there's a direct hit and rocks
>   come sliding down on top of Odo...
>
> **CRODEN :** *Odo!*
>
> He leans down and examines Odo, **who is unconscious...**

[image]

It's not especially clear what caused his injury but from reading the script, it seems likely that the writer originally intended there to be a lot more rocks!

He also gets punched out (by O'Brien) in DS9 : The Assignment but this is whilst in human (non-changeling) form

---

As regards phasers, there doesn't seem to be a setting that causes *unconsciousness* in changelings. In [DS9 : Homefront](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/483.txt) we see them testing a "phaser sweep" that they think will force a concealed shapeshifter back into their liquid form and may prevent them from escaping.

> **BENTEEN :** *Three point one. **If we set the phasers at three point four, we should be able to stun any Changeling we hit and force them
>   back into a gelatinous state.***
>
> **ODO :** *I would make it three point five just to be on the safe side. But if you want to do more testing, you'll have to find another
>   guinea pig. I've been shot quite enough for one day.*

At higher phaser settings, changelings simply [explode](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20410/what-happens-to-odo-when-he-is-hit-by-a-phaser)

Answer (score 7):

Odo was knocked unconscious by a falling rock in the *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine* episode "Vortex".

Comment: Good point. I'd be tempted to call this [Early Installment Weirdness](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EarlyInstallmentWeirdness) though, as later on in episodes like The Ship, it's established that no amount of physical damage can harm shapeshifters.

Comment: But the cellular materials which comprise them, though flexible are likely to be able to withstand a certain amount of force before needing to rest or "reset". It should be theoretically possible to isolate something chemical and/or using variable phaser frequencies to temporarily stun them. Probably would require research to find the proper technology. But they are alive, they are created with cellular material so in theory, there should be something that can cause them to be temporarily insensate.