# Does Odo lose consciousness when he goes into his bucket?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, changeling

Not sure if Odo is totally unconscious or if he retains some sort of awareness while "resting" in his bucket. What do the episodes say?

Comment: Interesting question... It's rather likely it's something that was never explained though =\

Comment: I think I remember something about him not able to get mentally tired and spends his time in his room thinking or something. Perhaps he was talking to Kira (towards the end of the series)? I can't seem to find the scene.

Comment: He can lose consciousness; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67640/can-changelings-be-knocked-out/67646#67646

Comment: He can lose consciousness, but does he do so when he goes into his bucket?

Answer (score 3):

I would say that he retains a reasonable level of awareness of what's happening around him. There's plenty of references to Odo's need to "regenerate" but it's never made explicitly clear whether this is accompanied by a major loss of consciousness.

When he meets another shapeshifter in [DS9 : Chimera](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/564.txt), Laas described "solids" thusly

> He has bumps on his forehead and          she has a wrinkled nose -- but
>             they're basically alike. **They're          bipeds that eat, sleep and
>             breathe. You and I are nothing          like them.**

Later, after he regains his ability to shapeshift in [DS9: In Purgatory's Shadow](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/512.htm) he comments that sleeping in a bed was one of the very few human pleasures (along with eating and drinking) that he enjoyed:

> **KIRA:** *I bet you can't wait to get all this put together so you can start shape-shifting around the room again.*
>
> **ODO:** *I suppose. Though I did enjoy sleeping in a bed.*
>
> **KIRA:** *There's nothing to stop you from sleeping in a bed if you want to.*
>
> **ODO:** ***Except that now when I'm asleep I tend to revert to my gelatinous state and slide onto the floor.*** No, the bed goes. I'm a
>   changeling, not a solid. There's no use pretending otherwise.

Comment: I don't understand how Odo could say "now when I'm asleep." Could he "fall asleep" as a changeling? Did he, or did he not, retain awareness while "asleep?"

Comment: @T-1000 - He seems to maintain an awareness but there's a lot of change between the earlier seasons and the later ones, after he's met with Laas, after he's joined with the link and after being made human and then merging with an infant changeling. As he grows and matures, his need for restful (unconscious?) sleep seems to disappear

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a direct reference for this, but later in the series he redesigns his room.  Someone visiting his room found it full of all kinds of weird shapes and structures.  Odo explains that it is not so much that he needs rest as that he couldn't hold one form indefinitely.  He further explains that now, instead of just relaxing in his bucket, he imitates some of the abstract sculptures in his quarters and, for want of a better word, stretches and tests his skill with shapes other than humanoid.  So, no, apparently he is never unconscious, even when resting.

Comment: I'm not sure that the script backs up what you're saying. *" don't use the... bucket anymore. I've kept it  as a reminder of how I used to be.  But now, when I need to regenerate, I simply revert to my gelatinous state... anywhere in these rooms. Here, I can experiment with different 
   shapes and textures... bring in 
   various forms to emulate... and I 
   can do it in private.".*. It isn't obvious that he's doing both at the same time.